# Remove last specific character in a string c#

Tags: c#, trim

I use WinForms c#.I have string value like below,

```
string Something = "1,5,12,34,";
```

I need to remove last comma in a string. So How can i delete it ?

Comment: Why do you have such a `string`? I assume because of a loop that concatenates commas to `int`s. You can use `string.Join(",", ints)` instead. That avoids trailing commas in the first place.

Answer (score 334, accepted):

Try `string.TrimEnd()`:

```
Something = Something.TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: This is the best solution because it works for all strings, including situations where you don't know ahead of time IF the string does in fact end in a comma, or not.

Comment: This is why I still search for solutions even for things I could easily write myself. Someone else has usually solved it. :)

Comment: So the single quotes weren't a mistake. Today I learnt char and string are defined with single and double quotations respectively.

Comment: This is not the best solution. I created a line with multiple commas.  Something.TrimEnd(','); removed all the commas instead of just the last one as the original question required. In the help tooltip it even states that it will remove all trailing characters matching the character(s) specified. However, it works well if your string always ends with one comma.

Answer (score 22):

[King King's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20246486/447156) is of course correct, and [Tim Schmelter's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246461/remove-last-comma-in-a-string-c-sharp-winforms#comment30196842_20246461) is also good suggestion in your case.

But if you **really** want to *remove the last comma in a string*, you should find the index of the last comma and remove it like this:

```
string s = "1,5,12,34,12345";
int index = s.LastIndexOf(',');
Console.WriteLine(s.Remove(index, 1));
```

Output will be:

```
1,5,12,3412345
```

Here is a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/GjzePO)</kbd>.

It is unlikely that you want this way but I want to point it out. And remember, the [`String.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method doesn't remove any characters in the original string, it returns new string.

Answer (score 6):

Try `string.Remove();`

```
string str = "1,5,12,34,";
string removecomma = str.Remove(str.Length-1);
MessageBox.Show(removecomma);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim psValue As String = "1,5,12,34,123,12"
psValue = psValue.Substring(0, psValue.LastIndexOf(","))
```

output:

```
1,5,12,34,123
```

Comment: Question was about C# not VB.

Comment: Answer was in VB but same for C# so it helped me.

Answer (score 3):

The TrimEnd method takes an input character array and not a string.
The code below from [Dot Net Perls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/trimend), shows a more efficient example of how to perform the same functionality as TrimEnd.

```
static string TrimTrailingChars(string value)
{
    int removeLength = 0;
    for (int i = value.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        char let = value[i];
        if (let == '?' || let == '!' || let == '.')
        {
            removeLength++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (removeLength > 0)
    {
        return value.Substring(0, value.Length - removeLength);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below

Something..TrimEnd(",".ToCharArray());

Comment: You can use `','` instead of `",".ToCharArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can convert it into Char Array first by:

```
string Something = "1,5,12,34,";
char[] SomeGoodThing=Something.ToCharArray[];
```

Now you have each character `indexed`:

```
SomeGoodThing[0] -> '1'
SomeGoodThing[1] -> ','
```

Play around it

Answer (score 1):

When you have spaces at the end. you can use beliow.

```
ProcessStr = ProcessStr.Replace(" ", "");
Emails     = ProcessStr.TrimEnd(';');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
string Something1= Something.Substring(0, Something.Length - 1 );

Comment: Won't this error if "Something" is an empty string?