# How do I remove the last character from a string only when it is a comma?

Tags: c#, string, replace, text-manipulation

I have:

```
String test = "Hello,";
String test2 = "Hello";
```

I want to replace the last character if it is a comma with an empty string. I currently have:

```
String var = test.Remove(str.Length - 1, 1) + "";
String var = test2.Remove(str.Length - 1, 1) + "";
```

That would always replace the last character, even if it was not a comma.

Comment: What if the string ends with multiple consecutive commas?  Should they all be removed, or only the last character?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove last specific character in a string c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246461/remove-last-specific-character-in-a-string-c-sharp) or [Trim last character from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20246461/150605)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.TrimEnd` like so:

```
String test = "Hello,";
test = test.TrimEnd(',');
```